# django not reading my models.py

Tags: python, django, django-models

Working with Ubuntu 12.04 headless server
Python v2.7.3
Django v1.3.1 FINAL

Python came preloaded, I installed django from apt-get python-django

I will note that I have setup and configured 2 servers for development use. Both for the practice and because I travel a lot and having a VM handy is always nice. However, this particular machine is giving me trouble and I cannot fathom the reason.

my previous setups where pretty straightforward. install ubuntu, install python-django, copy files to server, check permissions, run python manage.py syncdb, then run python.manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080 and everything worked. For some reason this is not working on this server. I'm completely lost as I haven't changed anything and I'm fairly certain I haven't done anything different.

Any help is appreciated and I offer Thanks in advance

```
   $python manage.py shell
   ...
   >>>import pwht.models
   >>>k = Device(serial="something", mac="something", ip="10.211.119.50", active = True)
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
   NameError: name 'Device' is not defined
```

My path is in the sys.path under manage.py

```
charles@Jobserver-Gibby:~/pwht/pwht$ python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:16:07) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['/home/charles/pwht/pwht', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/u
sr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
>>>
```

for the sake of completeness

```
charles@Jobserver-Gibby:~/pwht/pwht$ python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:16:07) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from pwht.models import Device
>>>
```

import django also works without issue though I have not listed it here.

Here is the other side of the coin I had forgot to mention:

```
charles@Jobserver-Gibby:~/pwht/pwht$ python manage.py syncdb
Creating tables ...
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
Creating table auth_user_groups
Creating table auth_user
Creating table auth_message
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table django_session
Creating table django_site

You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superusers defined.
Would you like to create one now? (yes/no): no
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
No fixtures found.
charles@Jobserver-Gibby:~/pwht/pwht$
```

None of my tables from models are created. This is true in Mysql as well.

Here are my files in the project

manage.py

```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
   from django.core.management import execute_manager
   import imp
   try:
       imp.find_module('settings') # Assumed to be in the same directory.
   except ImportError:
       import sys
       sys.stderr.write("Error: Can't find the file 'settings.py' in the directory containing %r. It appears you've customized things.\nYou'll have to run django-admin.py, passing it your settings module.\n" % __file__)
       sys.exit(1)

   import settings

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       execute_manager(settings)
```

settings.py

```
   # Django settings for pwht project.

   DEBUG = True
   TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

   ADMINS = (
       # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
   )

   MANAGERS = ADMINS

   DATABASES = {
       'default': {
           'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
           'NAME': '/home/charles/pwht/pwht/mydb.sql',                      
           'USER': '',                      
           'PASSWORD': '',                  
           'HOST': '',                      
           'PORT': '',                      
       }
   }

   TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'

   LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

   SITE_ID = 1

   USE_I18N = True

   USE_L10N = True

   MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/charles/pwht/pwht/media/'

   MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

   STATIC_ROOT = '/home/charles/pwht/pwht/static/'

   STATIC_URL = '/static/'

   ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'

   STATICFILES_DIRS = (
       '/home/charles/pwht/pwht/statics',
   )

   STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
       'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
       'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
   )


   SECRET_KEY = [purposely removed]

   TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
       'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
       'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
   )

   MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
       'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
       'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
       'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
       'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
       'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
   )

   ROOT_URLCONF = 'pwht.urls'

   TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
       '/home/charles/pwht/pwht/templates/',
   )

   INSTALLED_APPS = (
       'django.contrib.auth',
       'django.contrib.contenttypes',
       'django.contrib.sessions',
       'django.contrib.sites',
       'django.contrib.messages',
       'django.contrib.staticfiles',
   )

   LOGGING = {
       'version': 1,
       'disable_existing_loggers': False,
       'handlers': {
           'mail_admins': {
               'level': 'ERROR',
               'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
           }
       },
       'loggers': {
           'django.request': {
               'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
               'level': 'ERROR',
               'propagate': True,
           },
       }
   }
```

models.py

```
'''
Created on Aug 18, 2012

@author: Charles B. Gibby
'''
from django.db import models

class Device (models.Model):
    serial = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    mac = models.CharField(max_length=17)
    ip = models.IPAddressField()
    active = models.BooleanField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.serial

class Console (models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device)
    serial = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    active = models.BooleanField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.serial

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['device', 'address']

class Current_zones (models.Model):
    console = models.ForeignKey(Console)
    zone = models.IntegerField()
    temp = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    when_temp = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, auto_now=False)
    output = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    when_output = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, auto_now=False)
    man_sp = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    when_man_sp = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, auto_now=False)
    trim = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    when_trim = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, auto_now=False)
    clamp = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    when_clamp = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, auto_now=False)
    auto_sp = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    when_auto_sp = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, auto_now=False)
    sp_type = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    when_sp_type = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, auto_now=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s-%s' % (self.console, self.zone)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['console', 'zone']

class Message (models.Model):
    console = models.ForeignKey(Console)
    req_type = models.BooleanField() # 0 for Read and 1 for Write
    parameter = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    target = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    data = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    when_message = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, auto_now=False)
    tx = models.BooleanField()
    when_tx = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, auto_now=False)
    status = models.BooleanField()
    when_status = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, auto_now=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s-%s' % (self.console, self.parameter)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['console', 'when_message']

class Recorded_zones (models.Model):
    console = models.ForeignKey(Console)
    zone = models.IntegerField()
    temp = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    when_temp = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, auto_now=False)
    output = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    when_output = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, auto_now=False)
    man_sp = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    when_man_sp = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, auto_now=False)
    trim = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    when_trim = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, auto_now=False)
    clamp = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    when_clamp = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, auto_now=False)
    auto_sp = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    when_auto_sp = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, auto_now=False)
    sp_type = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    when_sp_type = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, auto_now=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s-%s' % (self.console, self.zone)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['console', 'zone', 'when_temp']

class Profiler (models.Model):
    console = models.ForeignKey(Console)
    climb = models.IntegerField()
    soak = models.IntegerField()
    hold = models.IntegerField()
    down = models.IntegerField()
    end = models.IntegerField()
    duration = models.IntegerField()
    when_duration = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, auto_now=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.console

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['console']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

3rd line in your first snippet; instead of

```
import pwht.models
```

did you try:

```
from pwht.models import Device
```

**UPDATE**: the `pwht` app is *NOT* included within your `settings.py` [`INSTALLED_APPS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#installed-apps). Therefore add `pwht` within your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: yes, to the same result, I edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: @Klemorali: Capital D in device

Comment: @Klemorali Did `syncdb` on the server run normally? I.e. did it create the db tables? That implies `models.py` is being read.

Comment: @Klemorali Is the `app` called `pwht` included in your `settings.py` [`INSTALLED_APPS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#installed-apps)?

Comment: Whether or not the app is included in INSTALLED_APPS is irrelevant as to whether you can import it. In fact your latest go, with capital D, appears to have worked, as shown by your copy-and-paste above: what problems do you still have?

Comment: python manage.py syncdb does not create tables for models found in models.py

Comment: @Josvic adding the line `'pwht',` to my settings.py seems to have done the trick. I'm still confused though, because it was not necessary to do this with any of my other installs. I was hoping to isolate the root cause for the purpose of understanding

Comment: @Klemorali Within `INSTALLED_APPS` I always include the apps whose code I intend to use. Otherwise management commands totally miss those apps, for instance `syncdb` or `test`. If this did fix your issue kindly mark the answer as correct.